# ¿Como puedo migrar correos de cpanel a hostinger?

Tags: wordpress, web, email, hosting, cpanel

Estoy intentando migrar los correos pero tengo un problema, al comunicarme con el soporte técnico de hostinger me dijeron que la mejor manera y la más fácil de pasar los correos es por medio de IMAP SYNC y lo estaba intentando hacer, pero no pasa nada, al sincronizarlo no se pasa ningún correo, ¿me podrían ayudar a como hacerlo? ¿O me podrían decir de que otra manera lo puedo hacer? Que sea sencilla. Muchas gracias.
Este es el paso a paso que estoy siguiendo:

[¿Cómo migrar correos electrónicos con la herramienta de sincronización IMAP?](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=es&u=https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/4469281-how-to-migrate-emails-using-imap-sync-tool)

Y ya me comunique con soporte pero me dicen que todo esta perfecto y ya, no me ayudaron para nada.

[image: LOGS]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo estás intentándolo hacer? Hay algún log del proceso? Considera editar tu pregunta y añadir esta información.

Comment: Ya la edito y muestro los pasos que estoy siguiendo.

Comment: Y qué te sale usando esa herramienta IMAP SYNC? Debajo de la configuración hay unos logs. Sin eso es imposible saber cómo ayudarte.

Comment: Ya te los pongo también.

Comment: Ya los puse, me dices si necesitas algo más.

Comment: Te está diciendo en perfecto español que no se pudo conectar al host1. Revisa la configuración de tu usuario para acceder por IMAP al servidor de origen y prueba hasta que te salga como en el Host2 (conectado e iniciada sesión, blablabla). **Hay que leer los logs**, como mantra para la vida en este negocio, que otro programador los puso para eso :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129722/discussion-between-seis-and-alfabravo).

Comment: ¿Quieres migrar las cuentas de correo (usuario y contraseña), los correos en si (el contenido de los mensajes) o ambos?

Comment: Solo quiero migrar los mensajes ya que las cuentas las cree igual en el otro hosting